# Use one join for SQL query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a SQL Server database and pulling several columns from subqueries (Invoice date, Est ship date, etc). How to replace multiple left joins with just one join and use the `case` statement in the `Select` statement? Or is there a better solution? Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT Orders.ID
       , InvDate.Event_Time     AS Invoice_date
       , EstShipDate.Event_Time AS Est_Ship_date
       , DelDate.Event_Time     AS Del_date
       , ReturnDate.Event_Time  AS Return_date 
FROM  
    Orders
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT EventType, OrderID, Event_Time 
     FROM Ship_LOG_TIMES) InvDate ON InvDate.OrderID = Order.ID 
                                  AND INvDate.EventType = '1'  --Invoice date
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT EventType, OrderID, Event_Time 
     FROM Ship_LOG_TIMES) EstShipDate ON EstShipDate.OrderID = Order.ID 
                                      AND EstShipDate.EventType = '2'      --Est Ship date
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT EventType, OrderID, Event_Time 
     FROM Ship_LOG_TIMES) DelDate ON DelDate.OrderID = Order.ID 
                                  AND DelDate.EventType = '4'  -- Delivery date
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT EventType, OrderID, Event_Time 
     FROM Ship_LOG_TIMES) ReturnDate ON ReturnDate.OrderID = Order.ID 
                                     AND ReturnDate.EventType = '5'  --Return date'
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and then improve your question, so people can understand what you want to do.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Also, please don't use this ugly left join syntax. You can just do left join tablename without brackets and put the columns in the above select directly

Answer (score 2):

You could try this query

```
SELECT o.ID
       , MAX(CASE WHEN s.EventType = '1' THEN s.Event_Time END) AS Invoice_date
       , MAX(CASE WHEN s.EventType = '2' THEN s.Event_Time END) AS Est_Ship_date
       , MAX(CASE WHEN s.EventType = '4' THEN s.Event_Time END) AS Del_date
       , MAX(CASE WHEN s.EventType = '5' THEN s.Event_Time END) AS Return_date 
FROM  
    Orders o LEFT JOIN Ship_LOG_TIMES s 
               ON s.OrderID = o.ID AND s.EventType IN ('1','2','4','5')  
GROUP BY o.ID
```

Comment: Taking Max value based on Eventype condition is not necessary it will work like 

SELECT o.ID
       , CASE WHEN s.EventType = '1' THEN s.Event_Time END AS Invoice_date
       , CASE WHEN s.EventType = '2' THEN s.Event_Time END AS Est_Ship_date
       , CASE WHEN s.EventType = '4' THEN s.Event_Time END AS Del_date
       , CASE WHEN s.EventType = '5' THEN s.Event_Time END AS Return_date 
FROM  
    Orders o LEFT JOIN Ship_LOG_TIMES s 
               ON s.OrderID = o.ID AND s.EventType IN ('1','2','4','5')  
GROUP BY o.ID

Comment: @AsjalRana no that would be invalid in SQL server (or MySQL with proper configuration)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a sub query like so:

```
SELECT Orders.ID, AggData.*
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT OrderID
         , MAX(CASE WHEN EventType = '1' THEN Event_Time END) AS Invoice_date
         , MAX(CASE WHEN EventType = '2' THEN Event_Time END) AS Est_Ship_date
         , MAX(CASE WHEN EventType = '4' THEN Event_Time END) AS Del_date
         , MAX(CASE WHEN EventType = '5' THEN Event_Time END) AS Return_date 
    FROM Ship_LOG_TIMES
    WHERE EventType IN ('1', '2', '4', '5')
    GROUP BY OrderID
) AS AggData ON Orders.ID = AggData.OrderID
```